# Build GDAL with CMake

Tags: gdal, build

As stated here: https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/CMake
GDAL is not yet ready to be compiled with CMake:

> **News**
>
> *2012-04-28:*
>
> Pilot project of CMake configuration for GDAL is being developed internally by ​Kitware. It should be delivered soon,
>   so stay tuned. Once first beta is released to the public, it will be
>   available for testing, improvements

But this is pretty old.
Any idea on the roadmap if always planned?
(I'd like to know which flag I can switch to enable python bindings because now it cannot find osgeo within QGIS).

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 1):

The CMaked GDAL with all needed dependencies can be found at nextgis-borsch repository. Take a look: https://github.com/nextgis-borsch/lib_gdal

Comment: Thing is that I already have many images libraries, proj, and so on and what I absolutely do not want is to have them installed a second or even third time. Does it handle personal installed of such libraries in /usr/local well?

Comment: @s.k Build script will try to use local installed libraries. If not found suitable library and if you specify to use external - they will be downloaded and build in place (without installing into your target system). That is your target operating system?